# Sunspot reindex with sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, sunspot, sunspot-rails

When i`m trying to reindex some records in background using sidekiq, nothing happend.

```
afisha.delay(:queue => 'critical').reindex_showings
```

But if i reindex this records without sidekiq, everything works.

```
afisha.reindex_showings
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the changes are not being "committed" to Solr. Once you've sent changes to Solr, they need to be "committed" in order to take effect (and become visible).
At the end of each webserver request, Sunspot automatically commits any changes you have made to the index. However no such processing takes place at the end of a Sidekiq job. You have a few options:

1. Tell Solr to auto-commit every so often (in solrconfig.xml).

   ```
   <autoCommit>
       <maxDocs>10000</maxDocs>
       <maxTime>30000</maxTime>
   </autoCommit>
   ```
2. Create a custom job that runs:

   ```
    afisha.reindex_showings
    Sunspot.commit
   ```
3. Amend Sidekiq such that it always calls `Sunspot.commit` at the end of each job (note that this might have performance implications).